# windows 10 system environment variable path back-slash "\" meaning

Tags: path, environment-variables

I am trying to find out HOMEPATH in Windows 10. When I input command SET in command prompt, it prints as

HOMEPATH=\

Please what does character backslash "\" mean here? Thanks.

Comment: you should ask this on superuser, not here on stackoverflow which is meant for dev related questions.

Comment: "\" for path means the same thing on Win10 as on any other Windows OS. Do you expect it to be different?

Comment: I don't know what the path \ is but only know the path beginning with Drive Root like C:\... Could you please tell what the path \ is in Windows?